# javaの継承を行った際に、同一パッケージ内に存在するにも関わらず、コンパイルエラーが発生します。

Tags: java, windows

下記の様に2つのjavaファイルを作成し、同一packageの「robot_pet」に保存しました。
この時、Pet.javaをコンパイルした後にRobotPet.javaをコンパイルした所、以下の様なエラーが発生しました。

```
RobotPet.java:4: エラー: シンボルを見つけられません
public class RobotPet extends Pet {
                              ^
  シンボル: クラス Pet
RobotPet.java:18: エラー: シンボルを見つけられません
        System.out.println("\nこんにちは! " + super.getMaster_Name() + "さん!" ) ;
                                         ^
  シンボル:   変数 super
  場所: クラス RobotPet
RobotPet.java:19: エラー: シンボルを見つけられません
        System.out.println("\n僕はロボット犬の" + super.getPet_Name() + "です。") ;
                                          ^
  シンボル:   変数 super
  場所: クラス RobotPet
エラー3個
```

以下の様に、同一ディレクトリ(robot_pet)に「Pet.java」と「RobotPet.java」は置いてあります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このコンパイルエラーの発生理由と解決策が分かりません。
ご教授頂けると幸いです。

#### 試したこと

package宣言を無くしコンパイルをしたところ、コンパイルエラーは出ませんでした。

##### 状況

- Windowsのコマンドプロンプトで実行。
- VScodeで書きました。
- VScodeは最新版です。

#### ソースコード

Petクラス

```
package robot_pet ; 

// ペットの名前と、飼い主の名前を持ち、
// かつ様々な処理を行うインスタンスを生成するクラス。
public class Pet {  

    // [ インスタンス変数 ] 
    private String pet_Name ;     // ペットの名前
    private String master_Name ;  // 飼い主の名前 

    // [ 初期化コンストラクタ ]
    public Pet (String arg_pet_name , String arg_master_name){

        this.pet_Name = arg_pet_name ; 
        this.master_Name = arg_master_name ; 

    }

    // [ インスタンスメソッド群 ]

    // ゲッター群
    public String getPet_Name()    { return this.pet_Name ; }
    public String getMaster_Name() { return this.master_Name ; }

    //　保存されているインスタンス変数の情報を基に、挨拶をするメソッド
    public void printIntroduce(){

        System.out.println("\nこんにちは! " + this.master_Name + "さん!" ) ; 
        System.out.println("\n僕は" + this.pet_Name + "です。") ; 

    }
    
}
```

RobotPetクラス

```
package robot_pet ;

// Petクラスから派生したRobotPetクラス
public class RobotPet extends Pet {
    
    // [ 初期化コンストラクタ ]
    public RobotPet(String pet_name , String master_name){

        super(pet_name , master_name) ; 

    }

    // [ インスタンスメソッド ]

    // 保存されているインスタンス変数の情報を基に、挨拶をするメソッド
    public void printIntroduce(){

        System.out.println("\nこんにちは! " + super.getMaster_Name() + "さん!" ) ; 
        System.out.println("\n僕はロボット犬の" + super.getPet_Name() + "です。") ; 

    }

    // 引数に応じて、異なる家事を行うメソッド
    public void  printWork(int option){

        switch (option){
            case 0 : System.out.println("掃除を行います。") ; 
                     break ; 
            case 1 : System.out.println("洗濯を行います。") ; 
                     break ; 
            case 2 : System.out.println("料理を行います。") ; 
                     break ; 
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

何とか解決できました。
どうやらコンパイルの方法が間違っていたようです。

Comment: 後からこの Q&A を見に来た方が助かるように、どうコンパイルしたらうまくいったのかの情報があると嬉しいです :)